# send() crashes my program

Tags: c++

I'm running a server and a client. i'm testing my program on my computer.

this is the funcion in the server that sends data to the client:

```
int sendToClient(int fd, string msg) {

    cout << "sending to client " << fd << " " << msg <<endl;
    int len = msg.size()+1;
    cout << "10\n";
    /* send msg size */
    if (send(fd,&len,sizeof(int),0)==-1) {
        cout << "error sendToClient\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "11\n";
    /* send msg */
    int nbytes = send(fd,msg.c_str(),len,0); //CRASHES HERE
    cout << "15\n";
    return nbytes;
}
```

when the client exits it sends to the server "BYE" and the server is replying it with the above function. I connect the client to the server (its done on one computer, 2 terminals) and when the client exits the server crashes - it never prints the `15`.
any idea why ? any idea how to test why?

thank you.

EDIT: this is how i close the client:

```
void closeClient(int notifyServer = 0) {

/** notify server before closing */
if (notifyServer) {
    int len = SERVER_PROTOCOL[bye].size()+1;
    char* buf = new char[len];
    strcpy(buf,SERVER_PROTOCOL[bye].c_str());   //c_str - NEED TO FREE????
    sendToServer(buf,len);
    delete[] buf;
}
close(_sockfd);
}
```

btw, if i skipp this code, meaning just leave the `close(_sockfd)` without notifying the server everything is ok - the server doesn't crash.

EDIT 2: this is the end of strace.out:

```
5211  recv(5, "BYE\0", 4, 0)            = 4
5211  write(1, "received from client 5 \n", 24) = 24
5211  write(1, "command: BYE msg: \n", 19) = 19
5211  write(1, "BYEBYE\n", 7)           = 7
5211  write(1, "response = ALALA!!!\n", 20) = 20
5211  write(1, "sending to client 5 ALALA!!!\n", 29) = 29
5211  write(1, "10\n", 3)               = 3
5211  send(5, "\t\0\0\0", 4, 0)         = 4
5211  write(1, "11\n", 3)               = 3
5211  send(5, "ALALA!!!\0", 9, 0)       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
5211  --- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
5211  +++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

broken pipe can kill my program?? why not just return -1 by send()??

Comment: i suggest copy the `msg.c_str ()` into a `char` array and then pass the array.

Comment: See the comment on my answer for the sigpipe

Comment: @rob You tried not to close the client and see if the error still happens?

Comment: also tried without closing. as i mentioned, if i take of the if(notifyServer) block, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the clients exits before the server has completed the sending, thus breaking the socket between them. Thus making send to crash.

[link](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sending-Data.html)

> This socket was connected but the
>   connection is now broken. In this
>   case, send generates a SIGPIPE signal
>   first; if that signal is ignored or
>   blocked, or if its handler returns,
>   then send fails with EPIPE.

Comment: but if an error occures during send it just supposed to return -1 to rv, and not crash the program. no?

Comment: `send` won't crash just because the other end of socket has gone away; it will return an error .

Comment: @Richie [link](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sending-Data.html) This socket was connected but the connection is now broken. In this case, send generates a SIGPIPE signal first; if that signal is ignored or blocked, or if its handler returns, then send fails with EPIPE.

Comment: Ensure that when the server tries to send something to the socket, the socket still exists in the client.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific way for this. It depends on the logic of the code. A server shouldn't try to write to a client when a client might have closed the connection, or if he should write, he should handle any errors that might occur (with signal handlers for example in this issue).

Answer (score 15):

You may want to specify [MSG_NOSIGNAL](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) in the flags:

```
int nbytes = send(fd,msg.c_str(), msg.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're getting SIGPIPE because of a "feature" in Unix that raises SIGPIPE when trying to send on a socket that the remote peer has closed.  Since you don't handle the signal, the default signal-handler is called, and it aborts/crashes your program.

To get the behavior your want (i.e. make send() return with an error, instead of raising a signal), add this to your program's startup routine (e.g. top of main()):

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   [...]
   signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the client exits before the second `send` from the server, and the connection is not disposed of properly, your server keeps hanging and this could provoke the crash.

Just a guess, since we don't know what server and client actually do.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following line of code strange because you define `int len = msg.size()+1;`.

```
int nbytes = send(fd,msg.c_str(),len,0); //CRASHES HERE
```

What happens if you define `int len = msg.size();`?

Comment: @rob: You don't want that. It delimits a C-string; it's not part of the string. `send` knows this and you're going one-past the buffer.

Comment: +1 is correct. For "foo", size() returns 3 and c_str() returns a 4 character buffer. If he wants to send the null character, he is free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, try to run the server inside `strace`. This will write lots of useful data to a log file.

```
strace -f -o strace.out ./server
```

Then have a look at the end of the log file. Maybe it's obvious what the program did and when it crashed, maybe not. In the latter case: Post the last lines here.