# in send() will it be ok to place the flag MSG_NOSIGNAL?

Tags: c++

I've asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162994/send-crashes-my-program)

I'm running a server and a client. A SIGPIPE signal crashed my server because of a broken pipe. I read that the above flag prevents that signal from being raised. My program now works and doesn't crash. But, i wonder what will be the over implications. What happens if i prevents SIGPIPE from being raised?

Comment: +1 interesting question. Most application authors blindly install a handler to ignore the PIPE signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't mind: it is just a different way of handling errors.

And using MSG_NOSIGNAL seems more elegant is a better way than ignoring SIGPIPE, since you may need this feature in another place of your program.